# Is there a way to open a registered screen directly from Swift

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using RNN, and I am trying to do a Modal that appears on top of a ShareViewController. And I would like to reuse a screen that I already did on JS. Do you think this could be possible ?

As RNN is all native code I think somehow this could be possible. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried already, can you share a [example]?

Comment: @koen Well I have been trying to call RNN from the Share target but I am not able to do it. I  tried to set  target 'Share' do
    pod 'ReactNativeNavigation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-navigation'
  end on the pod file and to add it to the -Swift file but is not working.